# How do I make the exposed filter values available as tokens for text areas

Tags: views, search

How do I display (or render in `twig`) the search term, entered in the search field. When you enter a search term and click on the search button, you will go to the search results page (view).

In the header of that view I want to display something like:

> Your search of [mysearcherm] has x number of results.

I build the search field with a `views exposed form` and `Search API.`

**Update:**
In the textarea of the views header I want to insert the *search term* as replacement token, but it's not available?

Answer (score 1):

You can show the relevant search term in `Text area` when you add it to the `Header` option in Views.

When you tick the `Use replacement tokens from the first row` option you will see the Replacement patterns tokens available, and below that global replacement tokens.

You can use something like:

```
<div class="messages messages--status">Your search of {{ name }} has [view:total-rows] result(s). </div>
```

Although you'll probably want to take care of plurals more intelligently and also use a twig conditional to not show anything if the Exposed form isn't used.

Comment: ok good idea, but the token for the search term is not available..?

Comment: Can you update your question with the Exposed filter config and the Text area tokens?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the global replacement pattern for the current page query parameter.

E.g. for */search?search_term_field_name=foo*:
`[current-page:query:search_term_field_name]`

Comment: This is just a workaround because it isn't a direct reference to the views exposed filter. There might be a better solution.